# How do you select all strings that contain words which have e.g. exactly two t's?

Tags: r

My assignment is: "Select all the strings that have words which contain exactly two t's."

I tried

```
grep("t{2}", text_strings, value = TRUE)
```

however it only selects the strings that contain two t's after another.

Comment: reproducible data please

Comment: Please give a sample of what you ran your algorithm on, what do you expect on this sample data, and the result you have with your current algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
grep("\\b[^t]*t[^t]*t[^t]*\\b", text_strings, value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#[1] "hotty" "total"
```

based on the example in the other post

```
grep("\\b[^t]*t[^t]*t[^t]*\\b", V,  value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#[1] "totally" "PotaTo"  "KiTten"  "ToTal"
```

---

Or another option is `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
text_strings[str_count(text_strings, "t")==2]
```

and with the other example

```
V[str_count(V, "[Tt]")==2]
#[1] "totally" "PotaTo"  "KiTten"  "ToTal"
```

---

Or with `stringir`

```
library(stringi)
text_strings[stri_count_fixed(text_strings, "t")==2]
```

#### data

```
text_strings <- c("hotly", "hotty", "total", "hottyt")
```